# Product of Monochlorination of 2-methylbutane

Tags: organic-chemistry

**Question:** Find out the number of products of monochlorination of 2-methylbutane including stereoisomers.

The given answer is 6, but why can't it be 7? I am getting 7 products, the one which I am getting but not in the answer is given below:

[image]

Other 6 Product,
[image]

Comment: Hard to tell what that diagram represents. It could be edited to show a clear diagram. See https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov//edit3/index.html for help. . For that matter, create th diagram there, and it can identify the name.

Comment: Thankyou for responding sir, I have changed the image

Comment: OP, have they asked with stereoisomers / without stereoisomers?

Comment: Could you draw all the 7 isomers you obtained

Comment: +1 for improving the diagram... but now you need to sow what the other 6 diagrams are. to see the difference. BTW, add all hydrogens, to show that all bonds are satisfied.

Comment: I shall answer! This is a confusing question, and requires the use of which are the similar compounds. I figured out the thing, and they are asking the number inclusive of stereoisomers.

Comment: @HarikrishnanM Yes Sir, they have asked including stereoisomers.

Comment: @ananta Sir,I have included the other 6 products too

Comment: @Rudresh don't the first 2 structures you have added match the one you drew originally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

Let us take the base compound, 2-methylbutane, as below.

[image]

I shall list down each compound, and explain my reasoning also.

This question is one of the more confusing ones as such, because people can easily leave out / count extra structures which might be same.

---

1. **1-chloro-2-methylbutane**

[image]

You must note that the below compound is also the same - the name will be the same.

[image]

Note that the **2nd carbon is chiral** in nature (marked by the $\color{orange}{\text{orange letter A}}$) and hence **we need to count this as 2 isomers - the d-isomer and the l-isomer.**

---

2. **2-chloro-2-methylbutane**

[image]

Note that this is **achiral** and thus is counted as **1**.

So, we've got **3**.

---

3. **2-chloro-3-methylbutane**

[image]

Note that the **carbon marked 'A' is chiral** and thus, this isomer is **counted as 2**.

That makes it **5**!

---

4. **1-chloro-3-methylbutane:** **No chirality is present** here, and thus it is **counted as 1**.

[image]

That makes it six, and we have come to the end of the list of monochloro derivatives from the reaction.

---

*The reason why you might have got 7 is that (refer point 1) you have counted the 1st compound as 2, but in fact those 2 structures point to the same compound*.

---

Comment: To the downvoter: is there any way in which I can improve my answer? As far as I know I am sure that I am correct in my reasoning.